# How to speed up loading data using async method in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mvvm

So far, I have a lot of data to load on my list. When I was using normal (sync) way to load data, it was about 20 seconds to load all the data. I made this asynchronous method and now I need about 7 seconds to load.
I wonder if there is a way to speed it up, for example, loading the first 20 cards as soon as the screen is opened, and then everything else? This is my code so far ..

```
public async Task<List<CardObject>> GetCardsAsync()
{
    using (var context = new MyCARDEntities())
    {
        return await context.Card
            .Include(f => f.Person)
            .Include(k => k.CardType)
            .Where(arg => arg.LastAction != "D" && arg.PERSON_ID != null)
            .Select(k => new CardObject()
            {
                    Id = k.Id,
                    UID = k.UID,
                    Person = new PersonBasicObject()
                    {
                        Id = k.PersonBasicObject.Id,
                        OIB = k.PersonBasicObject.OIB,
                        Name = k.PersonBasicObject.Name,
                        LastName = k.PersonBasicObject.LastName
                    }
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

and this is in viewModel

```
private async void LoadCards()
{
    var cards = await repKartica.GetCardsAsync();
    CardLst = new ObservableCollection<CardObject>(cards);
}

private ObservableCollection<CardObject> _CardLst;
public ObservableCollection<CardObject> CardLst 
{
    get => _CardLst;
    set
    {
        _CardLst= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CardLst);
    }
}
```

Comment: Profile the query you're sending to the database. Determine if you are sending an inefficient query and/or are lacking indexes.

Comment: 20 seconds and 7 seconds are both a very long time. One approach is to modify your app to just return the top 20 cards and see how long that takes. It might still be very slow. If switching from sync to async makes a big difference like that, could be you executing multiple queries or executing the same query more than once? There are likely ways to optimize, but if anything is making your app that slow it's better to find it and address it head on rather than trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a method async doesn't make a method faster, it just allows the method to surrender the executing thread to allow other code to run. This can make the code more responsive, but won't make retrieving that particular data any faster.

Firstly, loading a large amount of data is not a good idea if it can be avoided. Do clients need to see *all* of this data at once, or is it / can it be paginated into pages of 20 cards at a time? If it is, or can be paged, then consider employing a paginated collection which can query specific pages of data (utilizing `.Skip()` & `.Take()`) to pull back just 20 or so records at a time as the visible page changes.

The next thing would be to look at the query being executed. Run a profiler such as ExpressProfiler against your database and capture the SQL being run by EF. Execute a copy of those queries in Enterprise Manager to get an execution plan and see if there are index recommendations.

Other tips: When utilizing `.Select()` you do not need to use `.Include()`. Select will generate a query to pull from related entities automatically.

Are PersonBasicObject and CardObject your Entity definitions? If so, how many fields are in these entities that would remain un-filled by this Select?  Ideally you should use dedicated view models rather than passing entities. By filling entities using `Select()` to selectively populate data, you are composing an entity that is not an entity in the sense that it is not a complete representation of an entity. This can be inefficient due to variables that still take up memory but are not populated, and it is misleading and lead to bugs because you will have code that expects entities, and could get called/reused but then be dealing with "real" complete entities vs. incomplete entities that were loaded like this. Entities' sole purpose should be to represent data state, not transport for view state.